# ASP.NET DropDown list selected value ERROR 'ddldept' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items

Tags: asp.net, html-select

I am getting this error while clicking the edit button on my asp.net gridview.

> 'ddldept' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.

This is my dropdown's `SelectedIndexChanged` event

```
protected void dgbus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = dgbus.SelectedRow;

    //here am getting the error 
    ddldept.SelectedValue = row.Cells[2].Text.ToString().Trim();
    txtappcode1.Text = row.Cells[3].Text.ToString();
    txtappcode2.Text = row.Cells[4].Text.ToString();

    hdn.Value = row.Cells[1].Text.ToString();

    lblMsg.Text = "";
}
```

eveything is working fine, but when I try to edit a row having `row.Cells[2].Text` as 'Finance & Accounts'..
Is this '&' a problem?

My Gridview markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgbus" runat="server" class="table-format" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" 
              OnSelectedIndexChanged="dgbus_SelectedIndexChanged"
              OnRowCreated = "dgbus_RowCreated"
              OnPageIndexChanging = "dgbus_PageIndexChanging" AllowPaging="True" 
              PageSize="50">
     <Columns>
          <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" HeaderText="Edit Details" 
                            SelectImageUrl="~/images/modify.gif"
                            SelectText="Modify Approver" 
                            ShowSelectButton="True" />
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Approver ID" DataField="appid"/>
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Deptt" DataField="deptt" />
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Appcode1" DataField="appcode1" />
          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Appcode1" DataField="appcode2" />
     </Columns>
     <RowStyle  CssClass="misctext" Height="20px" />
     <HeaderStyle BackColor="ControlLight" CssClass="contentbold" 
                  Height="20px" />
     <PagerSettings PageButtonCount="5" />
     <PagerStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" CssClass="link" HorizontalAlign="Right" 
                 VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: sorry here's my gridview's selectedindexchanged ddldept.SelectedValue = row.Cells[2].Text.ToString().Trim();//here i am getting error..
            txtappcode1.Text = row.Cells[3].Text.ToString();
            txtappcode2.Text = row.Cells[4].Text.ToString();
           
            hdn.Value = row.Cells[1].Text.ToString();
       // }
      //  catch (Exception c)
      //  {
      //      lblMsg.Text = c.Message;
      //  }

        lblMsg.Text = "";
    }

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to find the value in the drop down list before attempting to set the `SelectedValue`, like this:

```
if (ddldept.Items.FindByValue(row.Cells[2].Text.ToString().Trim()) != null)
{
    ddldept.SelectedValue = row.Cells[2].Text.ToString().Trim();
}
```

So your full code should be this:

```
protected void dgbus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = dgbus.SelectedRow;

    if (ddldept.Items.FindByValue(row.Cells[2].Text.ToString().Trim()) != null)
    {
        ddldept.SelectedValue = row.Cells[2].Text.ToString().Trim();
    }        

    txtappcode1.Text = row.Cells[3].Text.ToString();
    txtappcode2.Text = row.Cells[4].Text.ToString();

    hdn.Value = row.Cells[1].Text.ToString();

    lblMsg.Text = "";
}
```